# dpkg- unknown control file error

Tags: ubuntu, packaging, dpkg

Under what conditions will lintian throw error `unknown-control-file`? the package is being created with no warnings but lintian is giving that warning and the error `empty-binary-package`

My directory structure is

```
debian

debian/DEBIAN

debian/DEBIAN/opt

debian/DEBIAN/opt/MyFile

debian/DEBIAN/control
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't put the files in `debian/DEBIAN` - they should be one level up, in `debian` itself.